# Overriding action in AccessibillityNodeInfo

Tags: android, accessibility

I have a custom view with an `AccessibilityDelegateCompat` for initializing `AccessibilityNodeInfo`, how do I avoid / remove actions that are default to the view like 'double tap to activate'?

My AccessibilityActionCompat looks like:

```
playVideoAction = new AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat
                .AccessibilityActionCompat(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS
                .getId(),
                "Double tap to play video");
```

and I call `accessibilityNodeInfoCompat.addAction(playVideoAction)` in `onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo()`.

I hear both 'Double tap to play video' and 'Double tap to activate'. I would like to only hear the play video action.

Comment: have you try ```AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.removeAction(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS)```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be overriding the CLICK action, not FOCUS, if you want to modify what's spoken for the primary interaction mode (ex. double-tap).

```
playVideoAction = new AccessibilityActionCompat(
    AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_CLICK, "play video");
```

Also, your description should only include the action that will be performed, not the interaction model -- so just "play video." The accessibility service is responsible for managing the interaction model and adding the "double tap to" description. This description will be different for other types of accessibility service like Switch Access or Voice.

Comment: neat. Is there a way to replace the whole "double tap to ******"?

Comment: @RedM this is late but you can just use `info.addAction(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_FOCUS);` and this will remove any default announcement